# Datetime column from mysql database is shown as String in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I use some arrays p1,p2. Their third parameter is a datetime as taken from mysql database. When i try to find the difference between these datetimes a warning appears: `Warning: date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given in ...`

Here is the code:

```
    $format = "Y-m-d H:m:s";
    $t1 = strtotime($p1[2]);
    $time1 = date($format,$t1);
    $t2 = strtotime($p2[2]);
    $time2 = date($format,$t2);

    $diff = date_diff($time1, $time2);
```

**New edit**
That's how i take datetime from db:

```
$temp=array();
foreach ($arr_smp as $column => $context) {
if($column == "latitude" || $column == "longitude" || $column == "date_time")
{
    array_push($temp,$context);
}
```

where `$context` is lat or lon or date_time

Can you help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show var_dump($p1[2]) and var_dump($p2[2]) ?

Comment: @Droid string(19) "2015-03-27 18:29:04" string(19) "2015-03-27 18:23:39" . I see that it says String (???)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error stated and you also write that value come from database table as string . So you need to convert them to `DateTime()` object and then get the difference. Please have a look:-

```
<?php
    $p1[2] = "2015-10-10"; // i assume that $p1[2] is like this
    $p2[2] = "2015-10-12"; // i assume that $p2[2] is like this
    $t1 = new DateTime($p1[2]); //conversion into date-time object
    $t2 = new DateTime($p2[2]); //conversion into date-time object

    $diff = date_diff($t1, $t2); // get difference
    echo "<pre/>";print_r($diff); // print difference
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/388744

Answer (score 1):

A few things are wrong with this code, firstly your format is invalid:

```
$format = "Y-m-d H:m:s";
```

Indicates hours, months and seconds, you need the following if you are after minutes (You can blame months and minutes for this one):

```
$format = "Y-m-d H:i:s";
```

The second issue is date_diff does not take strings as an input, so your error correlates to the arguments you have provided too it. I would re-write your code like this:

```
$dateOne = new Datetime($p1[2]);
$dateTwo = new Datetime($p2[2]);
$dateDiff = $dateOne->diff($dateTwo);
var_dump($dateDiff);
```

You can then use the date diff object to find your date difference values.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `datetime` and not `date`.